# jQuery: adding a class to child elements x number of times

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a div called starRating which displays 5 grayed-out stars. I am given a number and based on that number I need to add a css class that changes the grayed-out star to the colored one. Is this something I would accomplish in a for loop or with .each?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="starRating">
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star"></div>
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star"></div>
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star"></div>
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star"></div>
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star"></div>
</div>
```

And here is what I've been attempting to do. This seems as if I am over-complicating it.

```
$('.jquery-ratings-star').each(
        function() {
           for (var i = 0; i < nbrStarsVoted; i++) {
           $(this).addClass('.jquery-ratings-full');
                        }
 });
```

Comment: Kinda encrypted question(and code btw).

Comment: Hope you know how to vote for a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as this,

```
$('#starRating div:lt('+nbrStarsVoted+')').addClass('jquery-ratings-full');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PdaQJ/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery `:lt` selector like this:

```
$("#starRating").find('.jquery-ratings-star:lt(X)').addClass('star');
```

The `:lt` selector will select all the elements with the index lower than X and give them the class star